# I'm a total sucker

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

"I am trash",
my inner self cried;
that I might be clear -
I'm empty inside

What am I?

Comment: Anybody who replies, "You are trash, like you said" is *wrong*.

Comment: Hehe, you got me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it a...

> straw?

Because...

> once a straw is used to drink from, it becomes trash. It is hollow and empty. Crying could refer to its usage.

Comment: It’s precisely so!

Comment: This also fits with the title.

Answer (score 3):

"I am trash", my inner self cried; that I might be clear - I'm empty inside

What am I?

> A bottle of glass?

Comment: Your suggested answer may not always be empty inside. The true answer is *always* empty inside, unless you actively stop it from being empty inside (or stick something *realllly* sticky in there lol).

Comment: @Avi (but the riddle doesn’t actually say that - and if that’s an important distinction that, for example, rules *this* answer out, then it’s a distinction that should be made ...)

Comment: @Rubio The more critical identifier is the line "my inner self cried", rot13(juvpu qrfpevorf gur cebprff bs qebcf bs yvdhvq tbvat nybat gur vaare "snpr" bs gur fgenj)

Comment: @Avi  ... which is just as applicable to Trista's answer here. 
Short riddles often allow good interpretations and answers that were not intended, as happened here. If there is some reason (beyond "that wasn't what I was thinking of") why Trista's answer does not solve this riddle, it's not apparent what part of the riddle actually invalidates this response. Because it seems this should be at least as valid as the "real" answer you had in mind, your riddle may be "too broad"—you may need to tweak it to make sure invalid responses are demonstrably invalid.

Comment: @Rubio It may need to go, then. I’m not comfortable leaving the riddle up in its current state and pretty much all the clarifying modifications I can think of destroy the short and sweet surface.

Answer (score 0):

> An empty bag of chips.

Because

> Once the chips are eaten, it's trash?